# Excel Problem with a complicated situation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the data:

| Speed ranking | Weight ranking | Speed earnings | Weight earnings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 2 | 200 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 250 |  |
| 4 | 4 | 100 |  |
| 16 | 5 | 0 |  |
| 12 | 6 | 0 |  |
| 5 | 7 | 50 |  |
| 11 | 8 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 9 | 150 |  |
| 6 | 10 | 0 |  |
| 13 | 11 | 0 |  |
| 8 | 12 | 0 |  |
| 14 | 13 | 0 |  |
| 15 | 14 | 0 |  |
| 7 | 15 | 0 |  |
| 9 | 16 | 0 |  |

Assuming that the top 5 earners get:

- 250 for the 1st place
- 200 for the 2nd place
- 150 for the 3rd place
- 100 for the 4th place
- 50 for the 5th place

Here is what I want:

If the value in cell C2 is 0, then the person has not yet earned anything in the speed ranking. In that case, the formula should return a value in D2 depending on the weight ranking in column B, as follows:

- If B2 is 1, then D2 should be 250
- If B2 is 2, then D2 should be 200
- If B2 is 3, then D2 should be 150
- If B2 is 4, then D2 should be 100
- If B2 is 5, then D2 should be 50
- Otherwise, D2 should be 0.

If the value in cell C2 is greater than 0, then the person has already earned something in the speed ranking. In that case, the formula should return a value in D2= 0 and  depending on the weight ranking in column B, the formula must return a value of the gain for the next person on the weight ranking , let's say for example D3 , as follows:

- If B2 is 1, then the person has already earned the maximum amount and should not earn anything more. Therefore, D3 should be 0.
- If B2 is 2, then D3 should be the amount corresponding to the 1st place in the weight ranking, i.e., 250.
- If B2 is 3, then D3 should be the amount corresponding to the 2nd place in the weight ranking, i.e., 200.
- If B2 is 4, then D3 should be the amount corresponding to the 3rd place in the weight ranking, i.e., 150.
- If B2 is 5, then D3 should be the amount corresponding to the 4th place in the weight ranking, i.e., 100.
- If B2 is 6, then D3 should be the amount corresponding to the 5th place in the weight ranking, i.e., 50.
- Otherwise, D3 should be 0.

Here an example of what i want to have as a result :

[image]

Comment: @Azii0803: it's a great opportunity to learn how Excel formulas work. For that, you might try "Formula auditing", more exactly "Evaluate Formula": this gives you the opportunity to evaluate your formula step by step, which allows you to understand what happens and where it goes wrong.

Comment: You state "*f B2 is 1, then the person has already earned the maximum amount and should not earn anything more. Therefore, D3 should be 0.*" but your result table does not match that. In my answer I followed that statement which means the person with a weight ranking of 1 gets zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, had some fun with this, used extra columns but does work:

[image]

Must be a method to reduce the two extra columns needed. But have to go shopping :)  But I will come back to this as it seems challenging.